# Search crieteria in column title and if crieteria met count number of non empty cell in the corresponding column

Tags: google-sheets, count

I have a google spreasheet containing shift registration data and would like to count how many registration were done (via google form) per date.
However, using a google form repopulating each time data is entered, dates can appear in multiple columns

My Sheet1 looks lik this:

```html
Name |02.1 |03.1 |04.1 |02.1
-----------------------------
Paul |5-9  |6-10 |     |
Frank|     |5-9  |     |6-10
Tom  |     |     |6-10 |5-9
```

I would like to find a formula, to be placed in Sheet2, which can search for all columns containg a certain column title (02.1) and count how many non-blank cells are present in this same column.

So if looking for columns countaining text 02.1, the result should be 3.

This is the result I would like to achieve in Sheet2:

```html
      |Count |
-----------------------------
02.1 |3      |
03.1 |2      |
04.1 |1      |
```

As the file is expanding everytime somone is registering, I have about 100 rows, and I would like to reuse this all year round, so looking for the most dynamic solution, where not too many manual entry have to be done.

Comment: Hi Michael, can you share a copy of your spreadsheet (or a facsimile) so we have some data to work with?

Comment: Here is a copy of my spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rev7x_Vm_nHG8kMtwJkxD7CHLlT9eNL3px3NX3M5BWU/edit?usp=sharing. I try to have the formula on "Sheet 2" from Cell C2

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way (to my mind) is a custom function. You can use "header" argument to count non-empty values for columns with the **same headers exactly**, as shown below:

```
function COUNT_BY_HEADER(header) {
  // Here is a sheet with data to count (non-empty cells)
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = values.shift(), 
      count = 0;
  for (var i in headers) {
    if (headers[i] == header) {
      for (var j in values) {
        if (values[j][i]) count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

For example, you can write a formula: `=COUNT_BY_HEADER(A3)` for the third row of the Sheet2.

By the way, the shared Sheet2 contains more complex data (not exact equal to headers of Sheet1). Be also attentive with sheet names ('Sheet1' or 'Sheet1.'?)...